# Tail call async without await

Tags: c#, async-await

Take this `async` method:

```
public async Task<string> ReadStringFromUrlAsync(string url)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Because it returns the result of another task I believe I can do away with `async` and `await`:

```
public Task<string> ReadStringFromUrlAsync(string url)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    return reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

I noticed that the call stack in the event of an exception won't mention `ReadStringFromUrlAsync`, are there any other drawbacks to removing `aysnc`/`await` on tail calls in this way.

Comment: As written this is OK but you have forgotten to dispose of those resources. Now you need await again.

Comment: Good question, I came to this conclusion long ago when i saw allot of redundant await in our code base.

Comment: @usr thanks for that, it's a method I'm refactoring to `async` and that completely slipped my attention. It's a bad example for the question. I'm not going to edit, because answers reference it. I guess lets just assume in the case I'm asking about there's nothing that should be disposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine in most cases, but there is an important difference in exception behavior: any exceptions *before* the task is returned will be thrown directly rather than placed on the task. In your example, if `WebRequest.Create`, `GetResponse`, `GetResponseStream`, or `StreamReader(..)` throws, then in an `async` method that exception would be placed on the task, while in a non-`async` method that exception would be thrown directly.

BTW, if that's representative of your real code, I'd recommend using `HttpClient` instead, which was designed with `await` in mind:

```
public Task<string> ReadStringFromUrlAsync(string url)
{
  return new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it is an exact method from code, I didn't write it originally but was refactoring to `async`. Kind of slipped my attention that there's no disposing going on in my code. Will definitely change to `HttpClient` but with a `using` block don't you think? Like [these examples](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). And once I have a `using` block, I will need to use `async`/`await` again?

Comment: @weston: If you use a `using` block, then yes. But most real-world `HttpClient` usage caches the instance. A single `HttpClient` instance is capable of any number of simultaneous asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine with removing this `await` and `async`. In fact, Roslyn (new C# Compiler) team is thinking about making it an compiler [optimization](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1981).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. When you're just returning a task, you can just omit the `async` and return the `Task` directly, without `await`ing.